# Remote, standalone Bluetooth transmitter as an audio LINE-IN on a Windows PC

Tags: audio, bluetooth, windows

Is it possible to pair a remote, standalone Bluetooth transmitter to a Windows PC as an AUDIO SOURCE (recording line-in)?  I can understand that this is an atypical usage.  So, maybe it's not surprising that I cannot find a transmitter that explicitly mentions this usage.  But, this also makes me wonder if it's maybe not allowed/possible for some reason...

And if it's not allowed... why not?

Why would anyone want to do this?  Well, I use my PC as a DSP.  See...VST plug-ins for a DAW are generally a lot cheaper than standalone "audiofile" hardware components.

In a wired situation I:

1. send my sounds system's tape-out to my PC's line-in
2. do signal processing in the PC
3. send PC line-out back to my sound system tape-in
4. Run the preamp in tape monitor mode

In my current application I want to do DSP on TV audio. (Yes, only stereo for now.)

[image: Is this possible?]

Comment: Are you confusing *transmitter* with *receiver* (such as BT headset or speaker)? A BT transmitter outputs RF, not audio line out, unless that's an additional feature of the device. A BT receiving device takes broadcast RF input and sends out audio.

Comment: No. As I've already described... and, as my arrow shows... my somewhat-unique desire is to wirelessly SEND (transmit) audio FROM the device on the left (a TV) TO the device on the right (a PC).

There, on the PC, I will do some processing on the audio (Digital Signal Processing).

Not shown is the fact that I will then send DSP-processed audio from that PC to a sound reproduction device (e.g. powered speakers or headphones or a full-blown component audio system (pre-amp, amp & speakers)).

Comment: I am not sure I get this question. Windows handles sound input over BT just fine. The many BT headsets out there with microphones show this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have answered my own question (sort of).  It's actually a workaround to the fact I still cannot find any manufacturer able to explicitly state that you can configure a standalone Bluetooth transmitter as an audio input to a Windows PC.

The workaround is that... as it turns out... someone actually makes paired sets of Bluetooth devices.  One is a transmitter and the other is a receiver. I can implement my configuration with these.

I hope some imaginative readers can benefit from this workaround.

P.S. It does still bug me that I have to *outboard* the receiver. If anyone knows why Windows itself cannot !-BE-! the receiver... or what minimum transmitter BT version (e.g. 5.1) and feature(s) (e.g. A2DP) you need for Windows to recognize it... I would still be interested.

[image]